# Error on PDO SSL connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, openssl

I am getting the following error when trying to connect from my Windows box to my Linux box:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

This is the connection code:

```
    $dbE = new PDO(
                    'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=host_ip;',
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    array(                                                                                     
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY         =>'client_side_path\client-key.pem',
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT        =>'client_side_path\client-cert.pem',
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA          =>'client_side_path\ca-cert.pem'
                    )                                  
                   );
    $dbE->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo 'Connected';
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Is Open SSL configured on your Linux box?

Comment: I believe so but is there a way to test it?

Comment: Run the `openssl version` command.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 - is whats coming back. (PS will be back in Monday so may not respond till then)

Comment: This issue occurs with incorrect ssl installation on db server end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. The reason was because the path in Server B to the CA was incorrect. Its worth noting that to fix this I tried a connection outside of PHP directly from server A and it came up with an error "bad other signature confirmation" - I then loaded the CA cert and found it was empty. Rebooted the server, set the correct paths in both my.cnf *and* the server start call and all fixed. Really worth trying the mysql direct connection as it gave a very different error which was much more useful than the PDO one.