# PHP to MySQL using SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have a remote MySQL Server that requires me to use SSL for connections. I can connect to it using my terminal. But when I try to connect to it using PHP, I get the following error:

```
SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

It seems like the OPENSSL Handshake fails and the reason could be that my PHP is trying to connect to it using SSL3. The MySQL Server supports only TLSv1.2. Is there a way to force PHP to connect using TLSv1.2 ?

Here is my code used to connect:

```
<?php

ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, '/path/to/ca-cert.pem' , NULL, NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, 'hostname', 'user', 'password', 'dbname', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$link)
{
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r ($res);
    $db->close();
}    
?>
```

Things I have tried and possible problems:

1. Seems like openssl version mismatch. I can connect using my terminal and not PHP, so I checked my openssl version in the terminal with the one I get using phpinfo(), they were the same
2. PHP is possibly using SSL3 to connect, and the server only supports TLSv1.2, I wasn't able to find a way to force PHP connections to MySQL using TLSv1.2
3. I tried to observe the handshake using tcpdump/Wireshark, but I don't think the process even starts since there is a version mismatch.
4. I confirmed using "openssl s_client -debug" that the server doesn't support SSL3 which makes me think this is an issue on my computer, but not sure.
5. The reason I say my client might be using SSL3 is because of SSL3_GET_RECORD, I don't know for sure if I'm right in that too.

So, in short, Help!

**Environment:**

PHP 7.0.18

MySQL Server Enterprise version 5.7.18

OpenSSL 1.0.2g

OS: Windows 7, Ubuntu 16.04. Tried on both

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330686/how-to-fix-mysqlireal-connect-ssl-operation-failed-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182346/error-on-pdo-ssl-connection

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Both answers don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the driver that PHP used to connect to MySQL. By default, it is mysqlnd. And I don't think it was being able to connect using a SHA256 or better cipher to my MySQL Server, which is an enterprise version.

The other option for the driver is a libmysql library which Oracle does provide as part of the MySQL Enterprise Server (.deb files). I started with a clean OS(Ubuntu), and compiled PHP with the libmysql provided by Oracle, and then I was able to establish the connection successfully!

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php)